# Dropmenu center align

Tags: html, css

Here's the code. Notice that's NOT my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="drop">
<ul class="drop_menu">
<li><a href='#'>Link 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 3</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.drop_menu {
    background:#005555;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:30px;

}
.drop_menu li { float:left; }
.drop_menu li a {
    padding:9px 20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#5FD367; }
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    left:0px;
    top:30px;
    background:#5FD367;
    padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:168px;
    text-indent:15px;
    background-color:#5FD367;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#005555; }
```

My question is, how can I center the "Link 1", "Link 2" and "Link 3"? On the future, I'll add more "Link 4,5,6...", so I need a solution that doesn't require "almost centered", but a permanent solution.

Can you please help me?

Here's a link to JSFiddle where you can see the code working - http://jsfiddle.net/W5F3p/

My best regards

Comment: You have options, center your container or your container's child, the legacy way is to `margin: 0 auto` for block element or center the text inside it using `text-align: center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use text align in the container tag and set the list to display inline-block:

http://jsfiddle.net/W5F3p/1/

```
.drop
 {
   text-align: center;
background:#005555;    
 }
```

A little hacky but does the trick.

Comment: Yes, sorry I added width: auto and display: inline-block on .drop_menu

Answer (score 2):

If you're not supporting IE7 and below, I'd change the float:left on the li to a display:inline-block and then add text-align:center to the parent ul.

```
.drop_menu {
    background:#005555;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
.drop_menu li { display:inline-block; }
.drop_menu li a {
   padding:9px 20px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   display:block;
   color:#fff;
   text-decoration:none;
   font:12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#5FD367; }
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
     left:0px;
    top:30px;
    background:#5FD367;
    padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:168px;
    text-indent:15px;
    background-color:#5FD367;
    text-align:left;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#005555; }
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/s6Jcx/1/